# :dependent => :destroy destroys records that are no longer dependents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relational-database

Rails 4.2 running on PostgreSQL

I'm refactoring my database and moving some data around. Each `ProgressUpdate` belongs to a `LanguageProgress`. In a migration I move some `ProgressUpdates` from one `LanguageProgress` to another, then I destroy the `LanguageProgress` which no longer has any associated `ProgressUpdates`, however the destroy triggers the destroy on the `ProgressUpdates` that used to be dependent on it! Why's that?

Here's the relevant code in the migration:

```
LanguageProgress.find_each do |lp|
  if existing_lp = LanguageProgress.find_by(progress_marker: lp.progress_marker, language_id: lp.state_language.language_id)
    puts "LanguageProgress #{existing_lp.id} has these ProgressUpdates: #{existing_lp.progress_updates.pluck :id}"
    puts "LanguageProgress #{lp.id} has these ProgressUpdates: #{lp.progress_updates.pluck :id}"
    lp.progress_updates.each do |pu|
      pu.language_progress = existing_lp
      pu.save!
    end
    puts "now LanguageProgress #{existing_lp.id} has these ProgressUpdates: #{existing_lp.progress_updates.pluck :id}"
    puts "and LanguageProgress #{lp.id} has #{lp.progress_updates.count} ProgressUpdates"
    puts "destroying LanguageProgress #{lp.id}"
    lp.destroy
  else
    lp.language_id = lp.state_language.language_id
    lp.save!
  end
end
```

Here's what it prints out:

```
LanguageProgress 1073685945 has these ProgressUpdates: [1071256240]
LanguageProgress 1073691483 has these ProgressUpdates: [1071256239]
now LanguageProgress 1073685945 has these ProgressUpdates: [1071256239, 1071256240]
and LanguageProgress 1073691483 has 0 ProgressUpdates
destroying LanguageProgress 1073691483
destroying ProgressUpdate 1071256239
```

Here's the relevant bits of `language_progress.rb`

```
class LanguageProgress < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :state_language
  belongs_to :progress_marker
  has_many :progress_updates, dependent: :destroy

  validates :progress_marker, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :state_language }
  validates :state_language, presence: true
```

and `progress_update.rb`

```
class ProgressUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language_progress
  delegate :language, to: :language_progress

  validates :progress, presence: true, inclusion: ProgressMarker.spread_text.keys
  validates :month, presence: true, inclusion: 1..12
  validates :year, presence: true, inclusion: 2000..Time.now.year
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :language_progress, presence: true

  before_destroy{ |pu| puts "destroying ProgressUpdate #{pu.id}" }

end
```

Comment: My work-around is to use `delete` instead of `destroy` in the migration, but the question still stands.

Comment: At a guess, I'd try reloading the `lp` after moving the other processes (and before destroying it). The instance variable probably contains references to what it thinks are still processes that belong to it (even though they no longer do).

Comment: @TarynEast brilliant! It worked! Make it an answer and I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: I agree with @TarynEast's idea. To confirm this (although you'll destroy more records in the process, so don't do this in production), you could list `lp`'s ProgressUpdates after the reassignment, not just the count. If it tells you it has 0 ProgressUpdates, but still lists one, then you'll know that's what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd try reloading the `lp` after moving the other processes (and before destroying it).

The instance variable probably contains references to what it thinks are still processes that belong to it (even though they no longer do).